# Error in Converting nvarchar to int

Tags: sql

I have one table `#DateDay_temp` in which there is a column `ExtraAdultPrice` of type `NVARCHAR(20)`. When I am trying to run this statement in a stored procedure

```
DECLARE @ExtraAdultPAX DECIMAL(10,2)

SELECT 
    @ExtraAdultPAX = SUM(CAST((CASE ISNULL(ExtraAdultPrice, '') 
                                  WHEN '' THEN 0 
                                  ELSE ExtraAdultPrice END) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) 
FROM #DateDay_temp;
```

When I am passing the value 54.56 in the `ExtraAdultPrice`" column, I get the error

> *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '54.56' to data
>   type int.*

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `54.56` is **not** an `int` value .....

Comment: And **WHY** is a price column of type `NVARCHAR(20)` ?!?!?!?

Comment: Because it can have any values

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this error happens because of the fact you have a `0` in your `CASE` statement; therefore, the "type" of the `CASE` statement is decided to be an `INT` - which is completely wrong here....

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
    @ExtraAdultPAX = SUM(CAST((CASE ISNULL(ExtraAdultPrice, '') 
                                 WHEN '' THEN 0.00   <<== use "0.00" instead of just "0" !!
                                 ELSE ExtraAdultPrice 
                               END) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) 
FROM 
    #DateDay_temp;
```

Now, everything should be `DECIMAL(10,2)` and there shouldn't be any attempt to convert your values to an `INT`

Comment: That does change the semantics. The OP's original code would treat either `NULL` or empty string as zero. If they are only concerned about `NULL` then these are ignored in `SUM` anyway.

Comment: @marc_s : When ExtraAdultPrice is geeting  Null or blank value then I am getting the error "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Comment: @palakmehta: updated my response - now it should convert both NULL and empty spaces into `0.00` and sum it up as a `DECIMAL(10,2)`

Comment: When I am passing the integer values I am getting the error "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."

Answer (score 0):

54.56 isn't an int because of the decimal point.

Comment: This is where I am stuck in .

Comment: As @marc_s suggested you need to use a decimal if you which to keep the decimal point.